# SSL error only in python command window with apify request

Tags: python, command-line, python-requests, apify

I am trying to use endpoint from apify.com. When I run my request in web browser with token everything is fine but if I run my request via requests library from python console I am getting following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /endpoint?token=token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

Moreover if I set `verify = False` in my request than request is working. Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to install internal company SSL package for managing SSL connection from python. There was a recent change.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue come up a few weeks ago.

```
>>> pip install certifi
>>> python -m certifi
```

I'm not certain that one needs to actually call the module to get it's functionality, but I did and it solved the error.  More info on Certifi [here](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/).  It is also a recommended package extension to requests from their [website](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/community/recommended/#certifi-ca-bundle).  I added those lasts bits because I was wary of installing a package that ostensibly was never called after installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I tried it and it is still not working. I tried also `pip install --upgrade certifi` but it also don't help. I tried also in different command lines like cmdr or PowerShell but still the same :(

Comment: when you run `python -m certifi` are you getting the path to which the .pem file is saved returned?  I have also seen examples also importing certifi `import certifi` in the file in which you are using the requests module.  I did not have to do that, but it is another option.

Comment: Yes, it is returning the path. I tried also to import as you wrote but still the same :(